# Disable quotations marks on Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, odbc, laravel-7

I´m trying to use Laravel 7 with ODBC to connect to a DB2 Database. The problem comes when I try a normal SELECT statement like the following.

```
$test = Test::where('TEST', '1')->get();
```

Eloquent generates a SQL with quotations marks: `SELECT * FROM 'TEST' WHERE 'TEST' = 1`. My DB2 Database does not support the quotations marks. If I try the following, it works correctly.

```php
$test = DB::connection('odbc-as400')->table('TEST')->take(50)->get();

class Test extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'odbc-as400';
    protected $table = 'TEST';
}
```

Connection:

```
'odbc-as400' => [
            'driver' => 'odbc',
            'dsn' => 'X',
            'host' => 'X',
            'username' => 'X',
            'password' => 'X',
            'prefix' => '',
            'database' => 'X',
            'options' => [
                'processor' => Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor::class,
                'grammar' => [
                    'query' => Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar::class,
                    'schema' => Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\ODBCSchemaGrammar::class
                ]
            ]
        ],
```

How can I disable the quotations?

Answer (score 0):

For case, you can use `DB::statement()` of laravel

You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database)

Hope help you

Comment: Thanks but I can use the query builder, the problems comes with eloquent